# I have sent a string stored in Arduino's EEPROM via Raspberry Pi using HC-05, but it breaks when receiving on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, c, arduino-uno, raspberry-pi4, hc-05

Here is the code sent from Arduino:

```
void sendDescription() {
  delayStart = millis();
  delayRunning = true;
  message = readStringFromEEPROM(0);
  SerialDebug.print("{\"H\":[{\"Name\":\"Light\",\"ID\":\"00001\",\"Loca\":\"li\"}],\"F\":[{\"Name\":\"00000\",\"vR\":\"000000\"},{\"Name\":\"00001\",\"vR\":\"000000\"},{\"Name\":\"00100\",\"vR\":\"000000\"}],\"S\":[{\"stand\":\"AES\",\"ver\":\"128\"}],\"C\":[{\"stand\":\"blue\",\"ver\":\"4.0\"}]}");
  while (!SerialDebug.available()) {
    if (delayRunning && ((millis() - delayStart) >= 10000)) {
      delayRunning = false; // Prevent this code being run more then once
      SerialDebug.print("{\"H\":[{\"Name\":\"Light\",\"ID\":\"00001\",\"Loca\":\"li\"}],\"F\":[{\"Name\":\"00000\",\"vR\":\"000000\"},{\"Name\":\"00001\",\"vR\":\"000000\"},{\"Name\":\"00100\",\"vR\":\"000000\"}],\"S\":[{\"stand\":\"AES\",\"ver\":\"128\"}],\"C\":[{\"stand\":\"blue\",\"ver\":\"4.0\"}]}");
    }
    delay(1);
  }
  while (true) {
    reply_mess = SerialDebug.readString();
    if (reply_mess == "Resend") {
      Serial.println(String(reply_mess));

      //SerialDebug.print(EEPROM.readString(address));
      //Serial.println(EEPROM.readString(address));
      SerialDebug.print("{\"H\":[{\"Name\":\"Light\",\"ID\":\"00001\",\"Loca\":\"li\"}],\"F\":[{\"Name\":\"00000\",\"vR\":\"000000\"},{\"Name\":\"00001\",\"vR\":\"000000\"},{\"Name\":\"00100\",\"vR\":\"000000\"}],\"S\":[{\"stand\":\"AES\",\"ver\":\"128\"}],\"C\":[{\"stand\":\"blue\",\"ver\":\"4.0\"}]}");
      while (!SerialDebug.available()) {
        delay(1);
      }
      continue;
    }
    if (reply_mess == "OK") {
      SerialDebug.print(String("O"));
      break;
    }
    else {
      Serial.println(String(reply_mess));
      Serial.println(String("ERROR DESSCRIPTION"));
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code to receive the character string stored in the EEPROM sent from the Arduino of the Raspberry Pi

```
def receiveDescription():
    while True:
        while True:
            rcv = ser.read();
            sleep(0.03)
            data_left = ser.inWaiting()   # Check for remaining byte
            rcv += ser.readline(data_left)
            break
        if chr(rcv[len(rcv)-1]) != '}': # chua toi uu
            print("Decription: {}".format(str(rcv, 'utf-8')))
            resend_desc = "Resend"
            ser.write(str(resend_desc).encode('utf-8'))
            continue
        else:
            print("Decription: {}".format(str(rcv, 'utf-8')))
            resend_desc = "OK"
            ser.write(str(resend_desc).encode('utf-8'))
            while True:
                rcv_ack = ser.read();
                sleep(0.03)
                ack_left = ser.inWaiting()  # Check for remaining byte
                rcv_ack += ser.readline(ack_left)
                break
            print("Reply: {}".format(str(rcv_ack, 'utf-8')))

            with open("description.json", "w", encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
                json.dump(json.loads(str(rcv, 'utf-8')), outfile, ensure_ascii=False)
            break
```

[This is a picture of Raspberry Pi. This is an image of Raspberry Pi receiving data sent over from Arduino using HC-05, but with incomplete information stored in EEPROM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGMc3.png)

I want the Raspberry Pi side to receive the following information:
{"H":[{"Name":"Light","ID":"00001","Loca":"li"}],"F": [{"Name":"000000","vR":"000000"},{"Name":"00001","vR":"000000"},{"Name":"00100","vR": "000000"}],"S":[{"stand":"AES","ver":"128"}],"C":[{"stand":"blue","ver":"4.0 "}]}

Comment: Show output and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to mix `read()` with `readline()` like that. Either send straight ASCII/UTF-8 data with newlines at the end of each *message* and use `readline()`, or, if you must send binary data, send a network byte-order byte count at the start followed by the corresponding number of bytes of binary data and use `read()`.